# How To (Semantically) Mark Up A (Theatre) Script / Play in HTML5

Tags: html, semantic-markup, microformats

How To (Semantically) Mark Up A (Theatre) Script / Play in HTML5?

For obvious reasons, it's hard to search for "play" and "script" without a search engine thinking you mean “play a sound" and “JavaScript".

How can I mark up a script (as in the document one would give to actors in a play) such that it is semantically correct, and easy to style?

For example, let's take the start of Hamlet

> Hamlet
>
> ACT I
>
> SCENE I    Elsinore. A platform before the castle.
>
> [FRANCISCO at his post. Enter to him BERNARDO]
>
> BERNARDO   Who's there?
>
> FRANCISCO  Nay, answer me: stand, and unfold yourself.

Fairly obviously, I think, one should start with

```
<h1 id="title">Hamlet</h1>
<h2 id="act-1">Act 1</h2>
<h3 id="scene-1">Scene 1</h3>
```

But, then I get stuck.

I've tried looking at MicroData, but Schema.org's CreativeWork[0] really doesn't contain much that would be useful in the case of a work of fiction.

Is it enough just to say

```
<p class="stage-direction">FRANCISCO at his post. Enter to him BERNARDO</p>
<p id="1"><span class="character bernardo">BERNARDO</span>Who's there?</p>
<p id="2"><span class="character francisco">FRANCISCO</span>Nay, answer me: stand, and unfold yourself.</p>
```

Or is there a better / more sensible way of doing things?

[0]http://schema.org/CreativeWork

Comment: You should have a colon and a space after each character name: `<p id="1"><span class="character bernardo">BERNARDO:</span> Who's there?</p>`. Currently, your line would read: `BERNARDOWho's there?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the idea of precisely specifying markup for dialogue has been abandoned, and the W3C now simply offers [some guidelines which pretty much equate to your idea of using paragraphs and spans](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#conversations).

Note that the `dl` element, which older sources - including the spec - had formerly recommended, should now definitely *not* be used: ["The dl element is inappropriate for marking up dialogue"](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-dl-element).

But of course all this might change next week, or month, or year…

Answer (score 1):

Does this provide any inspiration? [caesar in xml](http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/j_caesar.xml)